# grep words from sentences having a dot

Tags: grep

I am unable to grep words after the dot.

Example,

I want to grep some words from sentences like :

```
PF03059.12
PF03330.13
PF13041.15
PF13812.65
PF01535.77
```

I tried

```
grep -oh "\w*PF\.*\w*"
grep -oh "\w*PF\.[0-9][0-9]\w*
```

and the results are

```
PF03059
PF03330
PF13041
PF13812
PF01535
```

I would like to fetch the ones after the decimal as well.

Thanks

Comment: post the input sentences, don't post the final words as input

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
grep -e "\w*PF[0-9]*\.\w*" -h
```

Comment: No this does not work :( .. I need the numerals after the decimal!

Answer (score 0):

For a file like this:

```
$ cat file1
This is sentence PF03059.12 and should be ok
This is sentence PF03330.13 and should be ok
This is sentence PF13041.15 and should be ok
This is sentence PF13812.65 and should be ok
This is sentence PF01535.77 and should be ok
```

This seems to be enough:

```
$ grep -o "PF.[^ ]*" file1
PF03059.12
PF03330.13
PF13041.15
PF13812.65
PF01535.77
```

It actually captures all chars after PF (`.*`)and stops in first found space `[^ ]`

Answer (score 0):

How about to use `awk` instead `grep`? This will allow to write simple and more clear solution without regular expressions. Just try this:

```
awk -F. '{print $2}'
```

Explanation: `-F.` set field delimiter to dot `.` then `print $2` just print second field

Answer (score 0):

**Input file:**

```
$cat file.txt
PF03059.12
PF03330.13
PF13041.15
PF13812.65
PF01535.77
PF13812
PF01535
XXXXX
PFABC.666
123.456
```

**grep command:** (using `-P` PCRE)

```
grep -P 'PF\d+(?:\.\d+)?' file.txt
PF03059.12
PF03330.13
PF13041.15
PF13812.65
PF01535.77
PF13812
PF01535
```

If you don't want to match line without decimals like `PF13812`, change regex to:

```
grep -P 'PF\d+:\.\d+' file.txt
```